# How to get full html sourcecode after page dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, view-source

I need to save my `.php` file as an `.html` for backup with using PHP whenever page called (I am going to use `ob_start()` for it). But the page content is not static. I am using AJAX to load the content.

That's why `view-source:` does not show the dynamic data, only chrome inspector show them. But I need to save the page with all elements after page loads. Is it possible or not?

BTW after page loads, there is no any other ajax call (on click or something). Page loads all content on init.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand you need to emulate a browser

Comment: I was going to suggest Selenium with the PHP WebDriver binding. My guess is the OP will say it cannot be a testing framework - must be from operational server - so it cannot be done.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yep, you are right mate. In 2018, we still can't find a solution to this problem, even we use the latest technologies :)

Comment: Other solution would be getting json data in php with using `file_get_contents` instead of `$.ajax`. What do you think @RandyCasburn?

Comment: square peg - round hole; I don't understand the absolute requirement to use a server side language that is not available in the browser (PHP) to perform a task that can only be completed in the browser. So square peg - stated differently, you have the XY Problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem